# Unable to declare variable as IDataObject and Bitmap. codeproject thumbnail images from pdf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I get the source code from here by Jonathan Hodgson
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5887/Generate-Thumbnail-Images-from-PDF-Documents
I can run the source code ok

but when I try to write the code in my own project. I cannot declare two types of variable 
which is this part

```
Dim clipboardData As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
```

and

```
Dim pdfBitmap As Bitmap = clipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
```

The difference I can see is that the code by jonathan has a reference to .net 2.0
and my project is .net 4.0

but changing my project to .net 2.0 does not seem like a good solution 
I am wondering why can't I declare as iDataObject and Bitmap? 
I can see both iDataObject and Bitmap in object browser in my project, but Why can't I use it?

another difference is jonathan source code is a console application 
and my project is class library

thanks you for any response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that you have reference to the `System.Drawing.dll` in your class library's `References` folder.

From what I can tell the `IDataObject` interface is part of the Windows development API, `System.Windows.Forms` namespace (`System.Windows.Forms.dll`) for WinForms development and `System.Windows` namespace (`PresentationCore.dll`) for WPF development, so verify you have one of those two references in your class library's `References` folder.

Finally, verify that you have the appropriate `Using` entries for the above namespaces, like this:

```
Using System.Drawing
```

Comment: Thanks.. I got it .. I declare   'code'"Imports System.Drawing" and 
"Imports System.Windows.Forms" -- now this is working